# Is there a good way to surface error traces in production across event emitters / event loop boundaries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

Let's say I have:

```
const req = require('net').createConnection(80, 'localhost');

req.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error) // handle somehow
});
```

If error event occurs, I get

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80 }
```

In the terminal.

I'd like instead to see the full stack:

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/aleksey/error-handing-example.js:2:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80 }
```

Note: I obtained the full trace artificially like this:

```
Error.captureStackTrace(this);
const req = require('net').createConnection(80, 'localhost');

req.on('error', (error) => {
  error.stack += this.stack.replace(/^.+$/, '');
  console.error(error) // handle somehow
});
```

I can't be doing this for all errors, as it's not sustainable

Is there a way to do this:

- a. In a way that doesn't hurt production stability (longjohn claims that it's for development only)?
- b. Automatically?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a hacky thing I cooked up using `async_hooks` and overriding `Error.captureStackTrace`:

```
const ah = require('async_hooks');
const traces = new Map();

ah.createHook({
  init(id) {
    const _trace = {};
    Error.captureStackTrace(_trace);
    traces.set(id, _trace.stack.replace(/(^.+$\n){4}/m, '\n'));
  },
  destroy(id) {
    traces.delete(id);
  },
}).enable();

global.Error = class extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.constructor.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }

  static captureStackTrace(what, where) {
    super.captureStackTrace.call(Error, what, where);
    const trace = traces.get(ah.executionAsyncId());
    if (trace) what.stack += trace;
  }
};
```

The gist is:

1. Keep a map of asyncId => traces
2. Override `Error.captureStackTrace` to use the trace from that asyncId on top of the original stack

Not sure about its performance limitations, bugginess, and robustness, but that's all I could come up with .

Now if I have:

```
const req = net.createConnection(8080);
req.once('error', err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

instead of

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1084:14)
```

I get

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1084:14)
    at TCPConnectWrap.emitInitNative (internal/async_hooks.js:137:43)
    at internalConnect (net.js:840:26)
    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:294:19)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.emitLookup [as callback] (net.js:1006:9)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:62:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.emitInitNative (internal/async_hooks.js:137:43)
    at lookup (dns.js:142:19)
    at net.js:981:5
    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:294:19)
    at lookupAndConnect (net.js:980:3)
    at Socket.connect (net.js:915:5)
    at Object.connect (net.js:162:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/aleksey/epudos-lite/server/test.js:28:17)
```